# Angular2: Escape string inside an html attributre

Tags: angular, html-escape-characters, ng-bootstrap

So I'm trying to make use of ng-bootstrap component to integrate bootstrap on my angular 2 app.

Following the tutorial, I created an accordion-like structure to display the articles that I fetch from my server.

The template is like this

```
<ngb-accordion *ngFor="let article of articles">
  <ngb-panel title="{{ article.title }}">
    <template ngbPanelContent>{{ article.summary }}</template>
  </ngb-panel>
</ngb-accordion>
```

The problem lies in the fact that article.title amd article.summary may contain special html characters like

```
&quot;
```

So, is there a way to turn this into a single quote (')?
All the solutions I found thus far are for injecting html inside an element, which is not my case.

Any info will help a lot. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expression to replace those special characters with empty string like so

```
<ngb-accordion *ngFor="let article of articles">
  // Add this line, escape it so it won't terminate prematurely
  // Note: no curly braces
  <ngb-panel title="article.title.replace(/\"/g, '')">
    <template ngbPanelContent>{{ article.summary }}</template>
  </ngb-panel>
</ngb-accordion>
```

Comment: Sorry, my question was messed up. I was looking to output & quot; (minus the first space) :) Editing now

Comment: Correct. But note that I don't know which symbols will appear ( Articles are from an rss feed). I was kinda hoping that there was a standard way for doing this, like the way it is done for elements with innerHTML directive (described here http://lishman.io/angular-2-interpolation)

Comment: I am very confused about your problem. So your `article.title` contains html entities like `&quot;`, and you want to output those html entities as regular characters, so transform `&quot;` to `"`? or from `"` to `&quot;` ?

Comment: Then you should use single quote `'` to enclose your expression like this. `<ngb-panel title='{{article.title}}'>` that way, you don't have to worry about the double quotes terminating your expression too early

Comment: I 'll try this!

Comment: hmmm, same results :/ Maybe it has to do with how my server sends the json... Thanks for your time anyway :)

Comment: So if your value contains html entities, if you don't assign that string to an `innerHTML`, then those entities won't be decoded automatically for you. But you can always write a custom function using regular expression to transform those entities back.